# How do I get the values of all the nodes within the first and last child nodes of an element in C#

Tags: c#, regex, linq, xml-parsing

I have an XML node with the following structure:

```
<package>package <name>com</name>.<name>sample</name>.<name>app1</name>;</package>
```

The *name* tag can appear a random number of times, and what I want is to get the values of all the child nodes between the first and last child in the list of elements, to get a value like this: **com.sample.app1**.

I guess I can apply some type of regular expression to the value of the *package* node which always starts with "package " and ends with ";". Or maybe some `LINQ` or `lambda` expression?

What would be the most efficient way of doing it since I'm processing a large XML file and this node is part of it?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299195.aspx

Comment: If my answer doesn't do what you're after, please clarify :)

Comment: John you are extremely fast :)

Comment: It does thank you, I just needed to add the XNamespace to the "name" argument of the Elements method takes an XName

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well in this case I'd just use:

```
var package = string.Join(".", element.Elements("name").Select(x => x.Value));
```

(Where `element` is the `XElement` representing `<package>`.)

Or if there's a different namespace:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://some.namespace/here";
var package = string.Join(".", element.Elements(ns + "name")
                                      .Select(x => x.Value));
```

(Where `element` is the `XElement` representing `<package>` and `ns + "name"` combines a `string` with an `XNamespace` to give the right `XName`.)